# Customized select drop down arrow not working

Tags: html, forms, css, select, bootstrap-4

I have tried to customized the select drop down. But the arrow of the select is not working. I want to make it as this image. But it is how far I could reach. Here is the image of how I want it to be. Please have a look at it.

[image: example dropdown]

**HTML**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="selectdiv ">
  <label>
      <select>
          <option selected> Select Box </option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Last long option</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.selectdiv {
  position: relative;
  /*Don't really need this just for demo styling*/

  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: 50px 33%;
  background:rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.selectdiv:after {
    content: '\f078';
    font: normal normal normal 17px/1 FontAwesome;
    color: #2B2B2B;
    right: -44px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 15px 12px 0px 12px;
    border:1px solid #2B2B2B;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
}

/* IE11 hide native button (thanks Matt!) */
select::-ms-expand {
display: none;
}

.selectdiv select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Add some styling */ 
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  color: #333;
  background: transparent;
  -ms-word-break: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline:none;
}
```

I have added the codepen.io link here. Please look at it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzKrXK

Answer (score 0):

modify your .selectdiv:after css like this, change url with any image you want:

```
.selectdiv:after {
 content: '';
 background-color: #fff;
 background: url(http://icocentre.com/Icons/g-arrow-down.png?size=16) no- repeat right #ddd;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 background-position-x: 5px;  
 width: 10px;
 font: normal normal normal 17px/1 FontAwesome;
 color: #0ebeff;
 right: 11px;
 top: 6px;
 height: 34px;
 padding: 15px 0px 0px 8px;
 border-left: 1px solid #0ebeff;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
```

}

Comment: it is just overlapping with my div.!